# Is there a scenario where Java7's Hashmap implementation is preferred to Java8's implementation

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

As of Java8, our beloved `HashMap` behaves a little different.
If the key implements a comparable interface, each hash would contain a balanced tree instead of a linked-list.

This reduces the worst-time complexity in case of collisions from `O(n)` to `O(log(n))`, see [JEP180](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180)

Is there a situation in which upgrading from Java7 to Java8 would cause a degradation of performance of the `HashMap` as a result ?

Comment: I guess the performance would worsen if you have a really slow implementation of `compareTo`. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java8 will use balanced tree in number of entries in the bucket in > N, where N is chosen [empirically](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l257), and use list once again if that number is < K. I'd expect worse performance if number of entries in bucket changes in way that "treefyng / untreeifying" happens often. That might happen due to specific hash function.

Also I'm not sure if overhead for creating and querying tree is worth the profit for small N.